# Xcode 4.1, SVN source control, Update in menu accessible, but update button in version control greyed out

Tags: svn, version-control, xcode4.1

I know there are a lot of questions on here that are quite similar to mine, but I looked through as many as I could and never found anyone with this specific problem.

I have a access to an SVN server that seems to be setup properly. I have successfully checked out and committed code. The options under the file menu for Commit and Update are not greyed out.

There are new updates to the code in the server. I click File > Source Control > Update. A "U" pops up by the files that have been updated. The version control window scrolls down. The changes appear there. But the Update button in the bottom right corner is greyed out (http://cl.ly/8y3R).

BUT if I right click on the file in the navigator, go to source control, update selected files, it works perfectly fine. 
Is there some reason that xcode would let you just update everything at once from the file menu?

Comment: Clean the index files and Derived Data folder. And restart xcode.